# Calling getStringExtra("key") on my Intent gives me null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, registerforactivityresult

This is so simple but still doesn't work.
I simply want to pass a string to the ACTION_PICK Intent to retrieve it in registerForActivityResult.

Here is my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val gallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        gallery.putExtra("filename", "test")
        resultLauncher.launch(gallery)
    }

    private var resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { 
            
            val fileName: String = result.data?.getStringExtra("filename").toString() 

            Log.i("###", "Filename is $fileName")

        }
    }
}
```

First I'm creating the Intent and call .putExtra to pass a String, in registerForActivityResult I call `result.data?.getStringExtra("filename").toString()` but it prints out "Filename is Null".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That intent that is used to start an activity for result is not the same as the result intent. Therefore, the key is not in the result intent.

Comment: @ShlomiKatriel How do I make sure to access the correct intent?

Comment: It is a different intent. You will not get your string back. Forget it.

Answer (score 0):

> I simply want to pass a string to the ACTION_PICK Intent to retrieve it in registerForActivityResult

That is not supported, sorry. The `Intent` that you use to start the activity is not the same `Intent` that you receive in response. And, there is no requirement for extras on the first `Intent` to get copied into the second `Intent`.

Comment: Okay Thank you, so the way to go here is just declare a global string at the top, for example "private lateinit var fileName: String" and set it before calling the intent so I can use it in the registerForActivityResult method?
Thats how I originaly wanted to do it but I thought maybe there is a more clear way to do it

Comment: @TheUseraccawd: At minimum you will need something like that. Bear in mind, though, that your app's process can be terminated at any point when you are in the background. If you are using the Jetpack `ViewModel` system, hold onto the value in the `ViewModel` and use the `SavedStateHandle` to try to hold onto it across short-duration process terminations. Or, save it yourself in the saved instance state `Bundle`.